# dynamic ng-model using multiple dropdown and ng-reapeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

Hello every one i have a language multiple selection input. On select language i need to open textboxes of selected language with dynamic ng-model.
 this is my json and  code.

```
[{"id":"1","lang":"English"},{"id":"2","lang":"Arabic"},{"id":"3","lang":"Français"}]

<select class="form-control" ng-model="language" multiple required >
   <option value="" disabled="">Select Language</option>
   <option ng-repeat="l in lang" value="{{l.id}}">{{l.lang}}</option>
</select>

<div class="form-group" ng-repeat="lng in language" >
   <label class="col-md-2" style="padding-right: 0px;">Name {{lang[lng-1].lang}}</label>
   <div class="col-md-10" >

       <input type="text" ng-model="typename.lang[lng-1].id" required >
   </div>
```

Comment: Yes Rohit had checked it. Like same think i was implemented but it's not worked for me so that's  why i done it in some long way. but yes your logic is right. Appreciate you logic

Comment: Thanks Pankaj for the appreciation. Can you mark that answer as correct so that it will be useful for others also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

personally I would use ng-options instead of ng-repeat like this

Controller:

```
$scope.inputs = [];
    $scope.languagues = [{"id":"1","lang":"English"},{"id":"2","lang":"German"},{"id":"3","lang":"Spanish"}];
    $scope.showTextbox= function (option) {
       $scope.inputs = [];
       for(var i = 0; i < option.length; i++){
          $scope.inputs.push({name: option[i], value: 'test'+i})
       }  
    }
```

html:

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="language" ng-options="option.lang as option.lang for option in languagues"   ng-change="showTextbox(language)" multiple required ></select>
  <div ng-repeat="item in inputs">
  <br>
    <label>{{item.name}}</label><br>
    <input type="text" ng-model="item.value" required >
    <p>
       {{item.value}}
    </p>
  </div>
```

Here is a fiddle showing the changes [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a6qLu7wp/7/)

Comment: Thank you for answering but i have not an issue with option or ng-option both are working same.

Comment: Then I dont understand the problem what is not working?

Comment: i have issue that when i m select 2 option then 2 textbox will appear but i not able to get or set value within that textbox using ng-model.

Comment: So When u select English a textbox should appear with a value?

Comment: No just blank textbox will appear. i will fill the value int in and i need that value in controller.

Comment: Can u check the fiddle link again? I changed it maybe this is what u need but I am not sure

Comment: plz check this fiddle i need this type textbox and it's data.

Comment: I dont fully understand what u want but  the Data is in $scope.lang[selectedOption]

Comment: Whatever data i insert in that textbox that i need in controller using ng-model.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/a6qLu7wp/4/ whstever u enter is in $scope.lang[selectedOption]

Comment: sorry but this is not work for me. you set same model name for all textbox but i need that name dynamic or unique.

Comment: I dont get it u want to select 1 languague and have 3 Inputs with 3 different values?

Comment: but i select 3 values in dropdown that's why i have 3 input if i select 2 then 2 textbox will appear.

Comment: Thanx @stackg91 your appreciation your code work for me but i think this is lengthy code. but thanx for support.

Answer (score 2):

**Try this :**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl',function($scope) {
    $scope.lang = [{
 "id": "1",
 "lang": "English"
}, {
 "id": "2",
 "lang": "Arabic"
}, {
 "id": "3",
 "lang": "Français"
}];

$scope.submitLang = function(selectedLang) {
 console.log(selectedLang);
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <select class="form-control" ng-model="language" ng-options="option.lang for option in lang" multiple required ></select>
  <div ng-repeat="lng in language">
   <label>{{lng.lang}}</label>
   <input type="text" ng-model="selectedLang" required ng-change="submitLang(selectedLang)">
  </div>
  </div>
```